# using the PhoneNumberChooserTask for an app

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, windows-phone-8

please I want to know how to modify automatically a property of a contact (for example is name, is number....) using the PhoneNumberChooserTask in windows phone 8 application code
thanks

Comment: Have you tried anything? If so, post your code.

Comment: Please add any code block if you have or post your requirement in brief.

Comment: void phoneNumberChooserTask_Completed(object sender, PhoneNumberResult element)
        {
            if (element.TaskResult == TaskResult.OK)
            {
              



                element.PhoneNumber == "6" + element.PhoneNumber; //fatal error during building the project....
                                                                  //

            }
        }    I want to modify a contact automatically, or at least write a code in which the user will give authorisation to modify automatically a contact in is phone

Comment: I want to modify a contact automatically.....